# How to link a correct answer (text input) to its question ? (arrays)

Tags: javascript, arrays

For a homework, I have to make an interactive interface that can be a quiz. So I decided to make a quiz where the user has to input text and validate it through a button, in order to check if it is right.

So I listed both the questions and the answers in 2 separate arrays like so:

```
var questionsList = [
    "体調",
    "体温",
    "病気",
    "風邪",
    "食欲",
    "検査",
    "異常",
    "手術",
    "回復",
    "薬局",
    "傷",
    "火傷",
    "胃",
    "肩",
    "胸",
    "腰",
    "膝",
    "心臓",
];

var correctAnswer = [
    "たいちょう",
    "たいおん",
    "びょうき",
    "かぜ",
    "しょくよく",
    "けんさ",
    "いじょう",
    "しゅじゅつ",
    "かいふく",
    "やっきょく",
    "きず",
    "やけど",
    "い",
    "かた",
    "むね",
    "こし",
    "ひざ",
    "しんぞう",
];
```

The index number of each question is the same as its correct input's index number.
But I actually don't know how to write in JS to make it understand that each question's index number is linked to one correct answer that bears the exact same index number in the second array.

I tried to make a function to check if the anwser would be right:

```
var userInput = document.getElementById("user-input")

function checkIfRightAnswer(index) {
    if (userInput.value === correctAnswer[index]) {
        document.getElementById("feedback").style.color = "seagreen";
        document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "C'est juste!";
        showQuestion();
    }
    else if (!correctAnswer[index] && !ended) {
        document.getElementById("feedback").style.color = "red";
        document.getElementById("feedback").innerHTML = "Mauvaise réponse, réessayez encore une fois!";
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. The interface knows when the input is incorrect, so a feedback tells me that it's wrong. But it also doesn't actually know what the correct answer is. Even if I type it, it's wrong.

I'm new to this and I didn't expect much to go smoothly but it's been a whole day, and I actually don't know what words to look up to look for help.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue, not just snippets that lack context. And please provide a set of sample data with questions and answers in English, that will be much more comprehensible for the majority here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your `checkIfRightAnswer` function the specific index of the question from `questionList`. You could do something like this:

```
let question = document.getElementById("question"); //assumes 'question' is ID given to question html element
let indOfQuestion = questionsList.indexOf(question.value); //gets index of question

var userInput = document.getElementById("user-input");

function checkIfRightAnswer(indOfQuestion) {...};
```

Also, I'm unsure if this was intentional, but the `!correctAnswer[index]` in the `else if` statement will always be falsy assuming the index is within the same range of the `questionList` array length. I'm guessing you might mean this: `userInput.value !== correctAnswer[index]`.